How do you initialize PnPjs when it's running in the context of a SharePoint site, but NOT in SPFx?
I'm buildng a React web part that's going to run on a SP2016 on-prem site.
Usually when I do this kind of thing, I do all the data interactions using JavaScript's native fetch API. I've never had to worry about authentication because the code is always running in the context of a SharePoint page/site, so the user is already authenticated.
Now I'm interested in using the PnPjs library, but I can't seem to figure out how to initialize it with the current site as the context if I'm not using SPFx.
I've found how to do it with SPFx, and there are instructions for how to do authentication using MSAL if you are using it in NodeJS or in another SPA on a site that's outside of SharePoint.  But I'm in SharePoint.  Just not using SPFx.
I've tried
const sp = spfi().using(DefaultHeaders(), RequestDigest());
const listTitle = await sp.web.lists.getById('my-list-guid').select('Title')();
console.log(listTitle);

but that results in

Error: Unhandled Exception: TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL':
Invalid URL

So how do I initialize everything to essentially connect to _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl without doing .using(SPFx(this.context))?

It's only been an hour and I think I figured out a hack... at least it's working so far... But I want to see if any folks have a more "official" answer.

I suspect there is not an official solution but I'm interested to see the hack you came up with.

@DerekGusoff I posted an answer :)

Alright, no one seems to be answering, so here's what I did.
What is the SPFx context object? Just a JSON object. And while some of it is more complicated, like the httpClient and spHttpClient, some of it is just static data.
The error I was getting, "Failed to construct 'URL'", made me think that the PnPjs code was trying to use the SPFx context object to figure out the URL of the web to connect to. So I thought maybe I could fake enough of the SPFx context to satisfy PnPjs.
Thanks to typings and Intellisense, you can explore the shape of the SPFx context object in an SPFx project in VSCode, so I started poking around:

Through a little trial and error, and getting some error messages that matched up to what I was seeing in the context object, I came up with this:
const fakeCtx = {
    pageContext: {
        legacyPageContext: _spPageContextInfo, // actually, i just added this for good measure...
        web: {
            absoluteUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl // this, i think, is all PnPjs needed
        }
    }
}
const sp = spfi().using(DefaultHeaders(), RequestDigest(), SPFx(fakeCtx));

And that seems to be working so far. Granted, I'm only doing things within a web (lists, list items, content types, site users, etc.), so my PnPjs imports look like this:
import { spfi, DefaultHeaders, RequestDigest, SPFx } from '@pnp/sp';
import '@pnp/sp/webs';
import '@pnp/sp/lists/web';
import '@pnp/sp/items/list';
import '@pnp/sp/content-types/list';
import '@pnp/sp/site-users/web';

I would expect that if I were to try to do things at the site collection level, I'd have to add this:
const fakeCtx = {
    pageContext: {
        legacyPageContext: _spPageContextInfo,
        web: {
            absoluteUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
        },
        site: {
            absoluteUrl: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl
        }
    }
}

But so far I've been able to get lists and document libraries (and their items), expand an item's folder to get the folder's server relative URL, get user information based on an email address, that kind of stuff.
I haven't tried creating or updating items yet (or adding attachments - something else I need to do for this project), so we'll see how that goes. But if I get any other error messages that hint that something is missing from the SPFx context, I'll just try to fake that too.
Fake it 'til you make it! :D

I have the same problem,
However, I find the oldest pnp (discard) to develop it, because it seem that it does not need context for initialization
import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";
let w = new Web("{Absolute Web Path}");
w.get().then(w => { // ... });

By the way, instead of using yo to create spfx 2016 projects, you can use the latest React, Typescript, which is a great experience. Development with Vite is much faster than the waiting compile time required by gulp
